# Query to return results only if a value does not exist in any row

Tags: sql, oracle

Not sure if the title explains this well, but I have a table for logging. So lets say I have the columns `Order_ID`, `Status`, and `Capture_ID`. I am trying to get a list of all `Order_ID`'s that do not contain a `Status` of `Complete` in any of the rows that order contains. There can be multiple entries for each `Order_ID`.

So the rows can look like:

```
ORDER_ID      STATUS      Capture_ID
1245          COMPLETE    999
1245          ASSIGNED    999
1245          FAILED      999
```

So I have written a query that returns results that do not contain Complete. It just returns the failed results, the problem is it doesn't check if that `ORDER_ID` has other rows that have `COMPLETE`.

Capture_ID is used to track the status of the order. The Order_ID might have 9 other rows to do with other things, but capture_ID gets assigned to this order and has the 3 possible entries of failed, assigned, complete. Cpature_ID will be null for all other rows

Answer (score 1):

If you only want orders in the table, you can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select order_id
from t
group by order_id
having sum(case when status = 'COMPLETE' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

If you want to run this for all orders, then I'll assume you have an `orders` table.  Use `not exists`:

```
select o.*
from orders o
where not exists (select 1
                  from orderstatuses os
                  where os.order_id = o.order_id and
                        os.status = 'COMPLETE'
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this questions calls for the MINUS command.

```
Select distinct(order_id)
  from {table_name}
MINUS
Select distinct(order_id)
  from (table_name}
where status = 'Complete'
```

You can take the output from this SQL and use it for further queries, as needed.

Comment: The thing is, there are correct solutions (in the sense that they do what is required) and then there are good solutions. The differences are practical in nature; for example, two queries may both be correct, but one may run 100 times faster than the other. Then only the fast answer would be a *good* answer, even if both are *correct*. Solutions using `MINUS` are often correct, but very rarely "good" in this sense.

Comment: Also, `distinct` is not necessary with set operations like `minus` because they are set operations and so return a set (of unique values).